# How to go back to Previous Drawer Screen in React native

Tags: react-native

I am New to React Native. And I have created a screen for example

1. A screen
   Now inside drawer I have two screen
2. D1 screen
3. D2 screen
   Now when I Move from D1 screen to D2. and then I want to Go back To D1 screen By tapping Default Back Button Of react native I am Directly Going To "A" screen. So means I want To go back to Previous Drawer Screen. please if possible help me. thanks.

here is my code of D2 screen

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {View,TouchableOpacity,Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Signature from 'react-native-signature-canvas';
import { Card, Badge, Button, Block, Text } from "../components";
import { theme, mocks } from "../constants";
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton } from "react-navigation-stack";





const DigSign = () => {
        
  const ref = useRef();

  const handleSignature = (signature) => {
    console.log(signature);
  };

  const handleEmpty = () => {
    console.log('Empty');
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    console.log('clear success!');
  };

  const handleEnd = () => {
    ref.current.readSignature();
  };
  return (
    
    

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       
      <Signature
        ref={ref}
        onEnd={handleEnd}

        onOK={handleSignature}
        onEmpty={handleEmpty}
        onClear={handleClear}
        descriptionText={'Sign here!'}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DigSign;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom header back button and get back to D1 screen,

```
<View style={styles.headerContainer}>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.navigate("D1Screen")}>
       <IonIcon name="chevron-back" size={(window.width) * 0.06} color="#000000" />
 </TouchableOpacity>
 <Text style={styles.title}>D2 Screen</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass navigation parameter in your function and then use navigation.goBack() like:

```
export default function SignupScreen({ navigation }) {
return (
<IconButton
            icon="keyboard-backspace"
            size={30}
            style={styles.navButton}
            color="#5b3a70"
            onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        />
  );
}
```